# Upgrading OpenNebula database from 5.10 to 5.12 doesn't do anything

Tags: opennebula

When attempting to upgrade database from v5.10 to v5.12 from Step #7 (http://docs.opennebula.io/5.12/intro_release_notes/upgrades/upgrading_single.html#step-7-upgrade-the-database-version) I received the following output:

```
$ sudo onedb upgrade -v -u ****-S localhost -p '*******' -d opennebula
Version read:
Shared tables 5.10.0 : Database migrated from 5.4.1 to 5.10.0 (OpenNebula 5.9.80) by onedb command.
Local tables  5.10.0 : Database migrated from 5.4.1 to 5.10.0 (OpenNebula 5.9.80) by onedb command.

MySQL dump stored in /var/lib/one/mysql_localhost_opennebula_2020-6-18_15:59:0.sql
Use 'onedb restore' or restore the DB using the mysql command:
mysql -u user -h server -P port db_name < backup_file


>>> Running migrators for shared tables
Database already uses version 5.10.0

>>> Running migrators for local tables
Database already uses version 5.10.0

Total time: 0.03s
```

The expected behavior is that it should upgrade to database schema `v5.12`, but in this case here it doesn't appear to do anything as it's attempting to upgrade only to `v5.10`, but my database version is already `v5.10`.

I've confirmed the OpenNebula packages installed are v5.12 from `/etc/yum.repos.d/opennebula.repo`.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that, as the documentation says, "*User of the Community Edition of OpenNebula can upgrade from the previous stable version if they are running a non-commercial OpenNebula cloud. In order to access the migrator package a request needs to be made through*..." https://opennebula.io/get-migration/